# Integer value assignment in c++

Tags: c++

I'm pretty new to C++ and I have the following simple program:

```
 int main()
   {
      int a = 5,b = 10;
      int sum = a + b;
      b = 6;
      cout << sum; // outputs 15
      return 0;
   }
```

I receive always the output 15, although I've changed the value of b to 6. 
Thanks in advance for your answers!

Comment: Thats how it should be. You are using two values to calculate sum. So the values of a and b are used in their current state (5 and 10). It does not have any impact on sum if you change the value of b afterwards.

Comment: Since you mention you're new to C++, you might be interested in our [list of good C++ books](http://stackoverflow.com/q/388242/1782465).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Execution of your code is linear from top to bottom.

You modify `b` *after* you initialize `sum`. This modification doesn't automatically alter previously executed code.

Answer (score 2):

`int sum = a + b;` writes the result of adding `a` and `b` into the new variable `sum`. It doesn't make `sum` an expression that always equals the result of the addition.

Answer (score 1):

There are already answers, but I feel that something is missing...
When you make an assignment like

```
sum = a + b;
```

then the **values** of `a` and `b` are used to calculate the sum. This is the reason why a later change of one of the values does not change the `sum`. 
However, since C++11 there actually is a way to make your code behave the way you expect:

```
#include <iostream>     
int main() {
    int a = 5,b = 10;
    auto sum = [&](){return a + b;};
    b = 6;
    std::cout << sum(); 
    return 0;
}
```

This will print :

```
11
```

This line

```
auto sum = [&](){return a + b;};
```

declares a lambda. I cannot give a selfcontained explanation of lambdas here, but only some handwavy hints. After this line, when you write `sum()` then `a` and `b` are used to calculate the sum. Because `a` and `b` are captured by reference (thats the meaning of the `&`), `sum()` uses the current values of `a` and `b` and not the ones they had when you declared the lambda. So the code above is more or less equivalent to

```
int sum(int a, int b){ return a+b;}

int main() {
    int a = 5,b = 10;
    b = 6;
    std::cout << sum(a,b);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I don’t think mentioning lambdas will help OP at all, considering their self-professed lack of basic C++ skills.

Comment: @KonradRudolph I get your point, but imho lambdas should not be reserved for experienced coders but rather one of the very first things to learn about c++. Of course my answer alone wont help him much, but it might make him do some reasearch

Comment: @tobi303, *"expression templates lite"*. I like that, **+1**

Answer (score 0):

You updated the b value but not assigned to sum variable.

```
int main()
   {
      int a = 5,b = 10;
      int sum = a + b;
      b = 6;
      sum = a + b;
      cout << sum; // outputs 11
      return 0;
   }
```

Comment: You could modify the code comment when modifying the resulting sum.